# Do Global Secondary Index (GSI) in DynamoDB impact tables provision capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have queries for 2 use cases with different throughput needs being directed to one DynamoDB table.

- First use case needs read/write only using primary key, but needs at least 1700/sec write and 8000/sec read
- Second Use case utilizes every GSI, but queries that use GSI are few and far between. Less than 10 queries per minute.

So my provisioned capacity for GSI will be far less than what is provisioned for primary key. Does this mean when I do a write on the table, the performance upper bound is what I have provisioned for GSI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asked AWS Support same question, Below is their answer:

> Your question is worth asking. In the scenario you mention your read/write request in GSI will be throttled, and 10 writes / min will be the effective limit. This will create issues when ever you update your primary table, the updates will get mirrored to GSI. So either you should     Provision similar write capacity to GSI or do not keep attribute in GSI that will get updated frequently.
>
> Here is link to our documentation that will help you :
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.ThroughputConsiderations

Answer (score 0):

I think so. When you add new items they will need to be added to the GSI index as well, so the same capacity is needed there as well

> In order for a table write to succeed, the provisioned throughput settings for the table and all of its global secondary indexes must have enough write capacity to accommodate the write; otherwise, the write to the table will be throttled.

There're more details and use-cases here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.ThroughputConsiderations